# Constraint violation error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created this table as part of my assignment,

```
create table course (
    cnum char(4) primary key,
    title varchar(20),
    credits number(1)
);
```

The table has this check constraint cnum_ck

```
cnum like '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

When I tried to insert the following row

```
insert into course values('m130', 'xyz', 3);
```

It threw `check constraint cnum_ck violation error`. I'm not sure where I went wrong. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SQL Server patterns for the `LIKE`, and these non-standard wildcards are not supported by `LIKE` in Oracle (nor any other database apart from Sybase).  Instead, use regular expressions:

```
create table course (
    cnum char(4) primary key,
    title varchar(20),
    credits number(1),
    constraint chk_cnum check (regexp_like(cnum,  '^[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'))
);

insert into course values('m130', 'xyz', 3);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c396) is a SQL fiddle.

Comment: I'm curious why you unaccepted the answer.  Is there any particular reason?

Comment: People here know your answers are the best :) It may be the newbie doesn't know how to use SO

Comment: Just to complete the picture: "*these are not support by LIKE in Oracle*" - this is not specific to Oracle. LIKE as defined in the SQL standard only supports the wildcards `%` for multiple characters and `_` for a single character (and I think SQL Server is the only DBMS that deviates from that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . If you count MS Access as a database, then it also deviates, but differently from SQL Server.  (I updated the answer to be clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

The constraint uses regex

So it should be `regexp_like(cnum, '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]')`